# Необходимо сформировать GET или POST запрос к API с JWT авторизацией

Tags: php, wordpress, api, jwt

Помогите разобраться с запросом к API с JWT авторизацией. В идеале пример кода.
Сайт с которого будет выполняться запрос сделан на wordpress.
Вот документация к API - https://newapi.archimed-soft.ru/docs# интересует v3.
С запросами к API без JWT авторизации знаком.
Куда копать и что изучать? От бэкенда я далек, но больше не кому этим заниматься. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Генерируете токен с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
2. Потом в хедере его указываете

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => [
                                            'Accept: application/json', 
                                            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
                                            'Content-Type: application/json'
                                      ],
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT  => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE   => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 90,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
if ( ! $result = curl_exec( $ch ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( curl_error( $ch ) );
}
curl_close( $ch );
```

где $post - массив данных для отправки POST, $url - адрес, $token - токен JWT, который вы получили на первом запросе

Comment: То есть я самостоятельно генерирую JWT токен и использую в описанном вами коде?

Comment: @НиколайОсминин у Вас же все расписано в документации.  метод 1 - Авторизация (получение токена сессии) (https://newapi.archimed-soft.ru/api/v1/auth?token=823168edbe11ea47b041c09804097154)  - там получаете access_token. потом его используете в коде из ответа

Comment: @НиколайОсминин для генерации токен на jwt.io есть библиотека https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt